# Merge two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [country] => Array
        (
            [0] => France
            [1] => Canada
        )
    [capital] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paris
            [1] => Ottawa
        )
    [other] => value
)
```

Is it possible to merge the `country` and `capital` arrays ?

The desired output is the following:

```
Array
(
    [countries] => Array
        (
            Array 
                (
                    [country] => France
                    [capital] => Paris
            )
            Array 
                (
                    [country] => Canada
                    [capital] => Ottawa
            )
        )
    [other] => value
)
```

What I tried:

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$array) {
    $result[$key] = array_merge($array, $arr2[$key]);
}
```

Comment: What about the `[other] => value`? how do you know which field to combine?

Comment: @dWinder, `[other] => value` should remain in the new array. For how to combine, the value should be merged in the key order. So the first of `country` should go with the first of `capital`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have known field to modify use:

```
$arr = ["country" => ["France", "Canada"], "capital" => ["Paris", "Ottawa"], "other" => "value"];
$keys = ["country", "capital"];

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($k, $keys)) {
        $slice[] = $v; // get the array which need to be merge
        unset($arr[$k]); // remove him from the original array
    }
}

$arr["countries"] = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, array_map(null, ...$slice));
```

And now `$arr` is set.

Notice the use of `...` operator to explode the `$slice` array and the `array_map` with `null` which combine according to int keys.

This is the **most generic way** because if you want to change the field to merge you only need to do so in 1 place...

Comment: What's the difference with your first approach ?

Comment: Now the code is more generic - in the first post I used the `country` and `capital` string 3 times

Answer (score 1):

If `countries` -> `capitals` keys and length are the same and you need only those values to be combined you can simply increment through one of arrays. For example:

```php
$result = ['countries' => [], 'other' => $arr['other']];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr['country']); $i++) {
    $result['countries'][] = [
        'country' => $arr['country'][$i],
        'capital' => $arr['capital'][$i]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code it will works 100%

thank you.

```
<?php

$arr = [
    "country"=>["France","Canada"],
    "capital"=>["Paris","Ottawa"],
    "other"=>[]
];


$result = [
    "countries"=>[]
];

for($i=0;$i<count($arr["country"]);$i++){
    $data = [
        "country"=>$arr["country"][$i],
        "capital"=>$arr["capital"][$i]
    ];
    array_push($result["countries"],$data);
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```